# Subtracting the array, Regarding key in dictionary

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, nsset

I have two array let's say

```
NSArray *array1=@[ @{@"key1":@"A",@"key2":@"AA"},@{@"key1":@"C",@"key2":@"CC"},@{@"key1":@"E",@"key2":@"EE"},@{@"key1":@"G",@"key2":@"GG"}];
NSArray *array2=@[ @{@"key1":@"A",@"key2":@"AAA"},@{@"key1":@"Z",@"key2":@"ZZZ"}];
```

I want to subtract the array, This should be the expected reuslt,

```
NSArray *resultArray=@[ @{@"key1":@"C",@"key2":@"CC"},@{@"key1":@"E",@"key2":@"EE"},@{@"key1":@"G",@"key2":@"GG"}];
```

I tried the below code but didn't working

```
NSArray *extracted = [array1 valueForKey:@"key1"];
NSMutableSet *pressieContactsSet = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:extracted];
NSMutableSet *allContactSet = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array2];

[allContactSet minusSet:pressieContactsSet];

NSLog(@"%@",allContactSet);
```

Comment: Where did that `@"key2":@"MM"` came from in the expected result?

Comment: @vivek: NSArray *resultArray=@[ @{@"key1":@"C",@"key2":@"CC"},@{@"key1":@"E",@"key2":@"AA"},@{@"key1":@"G",@"key2":@"MM"}];
in your result array from where @"MM" comes 
i think your desired result is wrong plz update your question

Comment: Please proofread your question before posting, especially with codes (given or expected result) just to save everybody's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code

First get all key1 objects in temporary array. Then apply filter on array1 and check if your array1 object contain arrayKey1 object.

Make sure it will only check for `key1` key.

```
NSArray *arrKey1 = [array2 valueForKey:@"key1"];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:
                            ^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings)
                            {
                                if ([arrKey1 containsObject:evaluatedObject[@"key1"]])
                                {
                                    NSLog(@"found : %@",evaluatedObject);
                                    return NO;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    NSLog(@"Not found : %@",evaluatedObject);
                                    return YES;
                                }

                            }];
NSArray *arrSubtracted = [array1 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];

NSLog(@"%@", arrSubtracted);
```

Or you can use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock`

```
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray new];

[array1 enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop)
{
    if (![arrKey1 containsObject:obj[@"key1"]]) {
        [resultArray addObject:obj];
    }
}];
NSLog(@"%@",resultArray);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @VivekSehrawat Please check my updated answer. you can also use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` if you don't want to use predicate.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
NSArray *array1=@[ @{@"key1":@"A"},@{@"key1":@"C"},@{@"key1":@"E"},@{@"key1":@"G"}];
NSArray *array2=@[ @{@"key1":@"A"},@{@"key1":@"Z"}];

NSMutableSet *pressieContactsSet = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array1];
NSSet *allContactSet = [NSSet setWithArray:array2];

[pressieContactsSet minusSet:allContactSet];

NSArray *result = [pressieContactsSet allObjects];

NSLog(@"%@",result);
```

Comment: I want to filter with specfic key1

Answer (score 0):

Enjoy!

```
NSArray *array1=@[ @{@"key1":@"A"},@{@"key1":@"C"},@{@"key1":@"E"},@{@"key1":@"G"}];
NSArray *array2=@[ @{@"key1":@"A"},@{@"key1":@"Z"}];
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array1];
[resultArray removeObjectsInArray:array2];
NSLog(@"array %@",resultArray);
```

Comment: I want to filter with specfic key1